# Can you access iTunes shares from linux?

Tags: linux, itunes

The big news from today's apple event aside, one interesting feature is the ability to [share media between 5 home computers.](http://www.apple.com/itunes/whats-new/#home-sharing).

The PR is light on details, but apparently you have to be running iTunes on those other computers in order to gain access.

Is it possible to remotely access your libraries from linux?

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to go the other way around.

In fact, if you're happy to ditch iTunes and it's seeming need to reinvent the wheel, you can run a DLNA(or uPNP) server on a file-server and serve video, photos, and music to equipped devices, which range from TVs, Xbox360s, PS3s, other computers, dedicated decoder units, and more. And you won't be limited to some arbitrary number of clients, or be restricted to sanctioned codecs.

Unfortunately AFAIK you won't be able to use iTunes, and you'll need to workaround it somehow, like mount the DLNA share and make that your library. However Windows Media Player 10+ will work with it, as will numerous other free media players (I use Rythymbox, Boxee, and my 360 as clients).

Answer (score 0):

With the older versions it was possible, With the latest ones, not yet, though chances are someone would reverse engineer it sooner or later.

Of course, there's always the poor man's way of doing it, and mounting it as a share of some sort, or setting up a streaming app of some sort, on the same directory. Neither is as neat or easy as the way itunes does it though